Violation of work-energy theorem (WET) in deriving potential energy (PE) of current-carrying ring in a uniform magnetic field
In deriving the potential energy (PE) of a current carrying ring placed in a uniform magnetic field rotated from $ \theta_1 \to \theta_2$, we write:
$$ \int dW = \int \tau(\theta)d\theta$$
under the appropriate limits of integration. My text straightaway replaces $∫dW$ with $\Delta U$, which is my point of confusion.
Is it not a violation of the work-energy theorem (WET), which states that work done by external agents equals the change in kinetic energy and not the change in potential energy (PE)?

Did you see my answer?

I won't downvote this since you're new to the site, but please consider using the proper Mathjax formatting when writing questions;  moreover, try to give questions a clear structure so that by doing so users will have an easier time interpreting what you're trying to convey.

@Claudio Please do not downvote questions if they don't use proper MathJax. Edit instead. That helps the community in a positive way. Hope you understand.

I don't downvote because of lack of proper Mathjax use, but when the question shows very poor effort to the point it becomes unclear or not easily understandable, well then I feel entitled to cast my vote.

What is the name of your textbook

"Charged ring" does not seem to be a good description of the system, if you're after potential energy of magnetic moment in external field, because such magnetic moment is due to electric current in the ring. Mere presence of a stationary charge on the ring does not produce non-zero magnetic moment. With zero magnetic moment, potential energy does not depend on orientation of the ring wrt external magnetic field.

Also, WET states that work of all forces(external and internal) equals change in kinetic energy.

@JánLalinský admitted.....carelessness on my end. a current carrying ring is what I meant to convey.

@BobD Thanks for the answer, the book is NCERT Physics for Class 12 Part 2 (NCERT is a government of India organisation that published it)

@JánLalinský It seems to me your answer here:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/779708/how-does-a-magnetic-field-do-work-on-rotating-a-current-loop answers the OP's question also. Why not post it here, or indicate as a possible duplicate?

@BobD well it's related, but this question is not clear enough. So I've pointed out problems with the question instead.


Is it not violation of work-energy theorem (WET) as Work done by
external agent is the change in Kinetic Energy and not change in
potential energy (PE)?

In the work energy theorem the work is net work, which is the sum of all the work done on an object, not just the work done by an external agent.
Hope this helps.

okay....but how would one justify the replacement of ∫dW by del(U) straightaway?

To definitively answer that I would need to see more context. Perhaps they are simply providing the end result.

They simply write "The magnetic potential energy Um is given by: Um = ∫(θ )dθ  = -mBcosθ = -m.B (vector dot product)"

m, according to them is the magnetic moment....so its a vector.   The ring is charged, kept in a uniform magnetic field and taken from angle θ1 to θ2(where θ is the angle between magnetic moment vector and the magnetic field vector). The external force is hypothetical, can be assumed to be our muscular force in taking the ring between the said angles. Formula in use : Torque = m x B (vector cross product)

I am not much of an expert in electromagnetism but the entire reason behind my answer is that you got the WET wrong. I know that many textbooks do not write it properly, so it's not your fault.
The work done ($\sim W_{\text{done}}$) is equal to the kinetic energy ($\sim K$) only if there is no change in potential energy($\sim U$)(Also,considering that we are talking only of mechanical energy and all other forms of energy are not under consideration). In simpler words, if there is any change in PE, then the formula you need to use becomes,
$$W_{\text{done}}=\Delta U+\Delta K$$
Which is a simple derivation of
$$W_{done}=M.E.$$
This is what your text book probably used and not the WET.
Imagine, you are pushing a cart up a ramp in the ideal case. Then, the work will never equal change in KE but will be the above sum.
Similarly, if in a particular case, there is work done, but no change in $K$, then the whole work is attributed to the change in $U$.
As in this case, there is no change in $K$ but only a change in $U$ due to the magnetic field, your text prints it that way.
Hope it helps. Please upvote if it did.

There is usually no potential energy in WET because WET is about net work of all forces, including those inducing potential energy. Thus WET is net work of all forces = change of kinetic energy. One can modify WET to exclude some forces, and then get your formula, but this is not the standard WET.

I talked of only mechanical energy as I mainly concentrate on Newtonian mechanics. Hope you get my view. I had excluded all other forces in my considerations.

Your answer is misleading, because what you describe is not the standard work-energy theorem. So don't suggest somebody else got WET wrong - you've got it wrong. If you want to explain work and potential energy, you have to first define which conservative forces are excluded from accounting of the work, and are used instead to define potential energy.

Is it clear now?

WET is not limited to cases where potential energy does not change; if P.E. changes, WET is still valid. What is "M.E.", mechanical energy? Then you wanted to write $W_{done} = \Delta (M.E)$? Again, you have to specify what $W_{done}$ is - work of which forces? This equation holds for work of non-magnetic forces. Work of all forces is zero (if kinetic energy does not change).

That's exactly what I meant to say but I guess my verbatim was very unclear.
